# Catch exception from controller and send as response

Tags: api, asp.net-core

I have WebAPI application. Every response is based on this model

```
public class CustomHttpResponse
{
     public int status { get; set; }
     public string message { get; set; }
     public object data { get; set; }
}
```

Example resposne for autohrization, look like this

```
{
   "status": 200,
   "message": "Logged succesfull",
   "data":    {
      "firstName": "Test",
      "lastName": "User",
      "username": "test",
      "token": "AUTH_TOKEN"
   }
}
```

Now, I want to catch every exception, which was thrown in any controller and send response to user, like this

```
{
   "status": 500,
   "message": "Internal Server Error",
   "data":    null
}
```

I tried to use middleware, but `Invoke` method return type of `Task` and i don't know how to work with this. Another way, was to override `OnActionExecuting` from `Controller`, but there's `void` as return type and I don't know what to do that.

Comment: You could define a global exception handler class that will allow you to define custom responses based on the exception type. Maybe this link will be useful to you https://stackify.com/csharp-catch-all-exceptions/

Comment: Thank you. Solution with errorHanling to custom route in controller is wonderfull. I can send status 500 on Exception, but on my own exception type I can send error message to user. <3

Answer (score 0):

If this is for asp.net core then use configure method. Main thing over here is to see UseExceptionHandler.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();                
            }

            app.UseExceptionHandler(configure =>
            {
                configure.Run(async context =>
                {
                    context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                    await context.Response.WriteAsJsonAsync(new
                    {
                        Message = "Internal Server Error",
                        Data = default(string),
                    });
                });
            });
```